# Why does this change all instances of all of these variables in this class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, jupyter-notebook

I don't understand why when I change one variable in an object, it changes all instances of that variable in all objects.

This specific program was written to show a bug/feature that was written within a probability simulation that I programmed. In this file that I made  to represent the bug, I wrote a class called "thing" and there is one variable that is an integer called "gravity" and when I change one object's ".gravity", it changes all of them. Here you go:

```
import random
class thing:
    gravity = int
a = thing
b = thing
b.gravity = 9
ab = random.randint(1,2)

if ab == 1:
    a.gravity = 1
    print("1")
if ab == 2:
    a.gravity = 2
    print("2")
A = str(a.gravity)
B = str(b.gravity)
print("a.gravity = "+ A)
print("b.gravity = "+ B)
```

I would expect a.gravity to equal either 1 or 2 and b.gravity to equal 9 but b.gravity always equals what a.gravity does no matter what. I dont know what to do, any feedback would be great!.

Comment: There are a few issues with your class definition @MeTA2x Check my answer below

Answer (score 1):

You need to read up more of how to define classes in python: start with this, https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html

To begin with

```
 class thing:
    gravity = int
```

is not how you define a class in python, also I am not even sure where you got this syntax from, but the code works because you have defined a static variable with `gravity=int` which means there is one value of the field per class, and you are modifying that value as you go through your code by doing `a.gravity = ..` and `b.gravity = ..`, as you can see below

```
import random
class thing:
    gravity = int
a = thing
b = thing

b.gravity = 9
ab = random.randint(1,2)
print(a.gravity)
#9
print(b.gravity)
#9

if ab == 1:
    a.gravity = 1
    print("1")
if ab == 2:
    a.gravity = 2
    print("2")
A = str(a.gravity)
B = str(b.gravity)
print("a.gravity = "+ A)
#1 or 2
print("b.gravity = "+ B)
#1 or 2
```

as you can see when you do `b.gravity = 9` , `a.gravity` also becomes 9, and the same happens when you do `a.gravity = 1 or 2`, both `a.gravity` and `b.gravity` becomes 1 or 2

The correct way to define the class for what you want to do is

```
#Thing class
class thing:

    #Constructor where we pass value of gravity and assign it to gravity attribute of class
    def __init__(self, gravity):
        self.gravity = gravity
```

After this the way to create an object of class `thing` is by doing `a=thing(9)` which basically means a is an instance of class `thing` with gravity `9`, following this logic we will have

```
#Define instance b of thing
b = thing(9)
ab = random.randint(1,2)

#Based on ab's value, instantiate a
if ab == 1:
    a = thing(1)
    print("1")
if ab == 2:
    a = thing(2)
    print("2")
```

After this we will have your print logic

```
#Get the value of gravity for a and b
A = str(a.gravity)
B = str(b.gravity)
print("a.gravity = "+ A)
print("b.gravity = "+ B)
```

The outputs will be

```
1
a.gravity = 1
b.gravity = 9

2
a.gravity = 2
b.gravity = 9
```